# Laravel: Form display and logic in single route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I need to create some sort of form in laravel I use a single route for both form displaying and saving. For that reason I need to use `Route::any('login', 'LoginController@login')` which doesn't feel right.

For example my typical login form controller method:

```
public function login()
{
    // handle submit
    if(\Input::isMethod('post'))
    {
        if(\Auth::attempt(array('username' => \Input::get('username'), 'password' => \Input::get('password'))))
        {
            return \Redirect::intended('profile');
        } else {
            return \Redirect::back()->withInput()
                ->withErrors(['auth-validation' => 'Invalid username or password']);
        }
    }

    // show form
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('frontend/login');
}
```

The question is: are there any security risks of `Route::any` or anything other I cannot think of in the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any security risks only depends on what you are actually doing with the request and what conditionals and/or checks you are using to respond to the different verbs.

But, you can limit verbs with the `match()` method instead of the `any()`:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/uri', 'Controller@method');
```

Comment: Didn't knew there was such method, that seems much better approach to routing this kind of thing, thanks!